# Spark worker shutdown - how to free shared resources

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In Spark manual there is recommended to use *shared static resource* (e. g. connection pool) inside the worker code.

Example from the [manual](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd):

```scala
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    // ConnectionPool is a static, lazily initialized pool of connections
    val connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection)  // return to the pool for future reuse
  }
}
```

What to do when the **static resource** needs to be freed/closed before the executor is shut down? There is no place where to call the `close()` function. Tried a shutdown hook, but it doesn't seem to help.

Actually currently my worker process becomes *zombie*, because I am using shared resource which creates a pool of non-deamon threads (HBase async client) that means the JVM hangs until forever.

I am using the Spark Streaming *graceful shutdown* called on the driver:

```java
streamingContext.stop(true, true);
```

---

EDIT:

It seems there already exists an issue in the Spark JIRA that's dealing with the same problem

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10911

Comment: Care to share some code snippets?

Comment: My actual code is too complex. But let's assume the `ConnectionPool` has a method `close()` that needs to be called after work is finished. When do you call it?

Comment: In `close()`; block until all connections are returned, never let connections go loose. And call it for at the end of partition closure? That would be it, with given information.

Comment: That's right. But I want to reuse connection objects across multiple batches. It's very inefficient to open a new connection for each micro-batch.

Comment: No, no and no. You've probably thought it through as it is *too complex*. But sharing state or resources between batches which may also mean between machines sounds worse than inefficient and contrasts with distributed computing. You might be optimizing prematurely.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but how is the executor getting shutdown?

Comment: I am using the graceful shutdown on the Spark Streaming context (`streamingContext.stop(true, true)`). I expect the spark worker/executor to receive some Akka message to finish all tasks and terminate. The problem is in the termination - waits for all threads to finish.