# Is there a "hook" for the end of a stage/task in spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a Spark UDF which needs to have a specific file (MATLAB runtime in my case) installed on the local disk of the executor (we are using YARN). As I don't have direct access to the executor machines, I have to find another way to deploy my runtime on the cluster.
As the file is very large, I cannot install/delete it for every invokation of the UDF, so I thought about the following strategy:

- At the beginning of the UDF, I check whether the runtime is available locally under a specific path, e.g. the `tmp`-directory
- If the runtime is not yet installed, I fetch it from the HDFS and install in in `tmp`. This is only done the first time the UDF is called on an specific executor.

The above screnario works fine, but leaves my installed runtimes all over the cluster, so I want to delete them afterwards.

There seems to be no way to add shutdown-hooks for the executors ([Spark worker shutdown - how to free shared resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375080/spark-worker-shutdown-how-to-free-shared-resources)), is there another "hook" e.g. end-of-a-task hook?

Comment: I would try using the JobProgressListener.onJobEnd()/onTaskEnd(): https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobProgressListener  (it seems related to spark UI so not sure if it works in your case)

Comment: Just checking, but have you tried deploying the runtime using the --files option in spark-submit ? It is the obvious choice for this kind of things.

Comment: @RobertoCongiu Yes just for submitting this would be obvious, but my runtime needs to be "installed" be executing bash-commands...

Comment: @asettouf That sounds promising, I will look into that

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, you can listen for the end of a task (I just had the time to try it now), at least on a global level on the spark context with something the likes (I'll write something in scala later, as I can't run scala code at the moment):

```
//sc is the SparkContext
sc.addSparkListener(new SparkListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTaskEnd(SparkListenerTaskEnd taskEnd) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Task ended: " + taskEnd);
            super.onTaskEnd(taskEnd);
        }
    });
```

There are plenty of other listeners, see [SparkListener](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener)

Comment: I tried this out, the problem is that this code is executed on the driver, not on the executor... therefore it's no use for me.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth And you can't clean your resources with the `onApplicationEnd` listener?

Comment: does onApplicationEnd run in the executor?